# Remove characters between markers in a bash variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to remove unknown characters between 2 known markers from a variable using bash.

eg

```
string="This text d #! more text jsdlj end and mo{re ;re end text.text"
```

I want to remove all the characters between the last word "text " (before the end word) and the first occurance thereafter called "end" . ie between the last occurance of the word "text " after that the first occurance of the word "end", but keeping both these markers)

```
result="This text d #! more text end and mo{re ;re end text.text"
```

I'll be using it as part of a find -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'command; command...etc.' script.

I've tried

```
echo $string | sed 's/[de][ex][ft][^\-]*//' ;
```

but that does it from the first "ext" and "-" (not the last "ext" before the end marker) and also does not retain the markers.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: So far the outcomes are as follows:

```
string="text text text lk;sdf;-end end 233-end.txt"
start="text "
end="-end"
```

## Method 1

```
[[ $string =~ (.*'"${start}"').*('"${end}"'.*) ]] || :
nstring="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ;
echo "$nstring" ;
>"text text text -end.txt"
```

Required output = "text text text -end end 233-end.txt"

## Method 2

```
temp=${cname%'"$end"'*}
nend=${cname#"$temp"}
nstart=${temp%'"$start"'*}
echo "$nstart$nend"
>"text text -end.txt"
```

Required output = "text text text -end end 233-end.txt"

## Method 3

```
nstring=$(sed -E "s/(.*'"$start"').*('"$end"')/\1\2/" <<< "$string")
echo "$nstring";
>"text text text -end.txt"
```

Required output = "text text text -end end 233-end.txt"

## Method 4

```
nstring=$(sed -En "s/(^.*'"$start"').*('"$end"'.*$)/\1\2/p" <<< "$string")
echo "$nstring" ;
>"text text text -end.txt"
```

Required output = "text text text -end end 233-end.txt"

Comment: Your sed command has a syntax error: ``unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''``

Comment: Are you trying to parse some markup language like HTML or XML without telling us about it?

Comment: No, its for any text. In one of the current cases/uses, its for filename stripping, other cases for removing personal and other data from text files.

Comment: here is the filename stripper code based on the answer (called with scrpt.sh "marker1" "marker2" "starting-folder" ;): find "$3" -type f -name "*$1*$2*" -print0 | xargs -r0 -n1 bash -c ' cfname="$@" ; nfname=$(sed -E "s/'"${end}"'/@/g;s/(^.*'"${start}"')[^@]*(@.*$)/\1\2/;s/@/'"${end}"'/g" <<< "${cfname}") ; if [ "$nfname" != "" ] && [ "$nfname" != "$cfname" ] ; then echo "Renaming File from: $cfname" ; mv -n "$cfname" "$nfname" ; echo " Renaming File to: $nfname" ; fi ; ' _ ; echo "Done."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** question has been updated with more details for dealing with a string that contains multiple *start* and *end* markers.

The new input string:

> This text d #! more text jsdlj end and mo{re ;re end text.text

Test case:

- *start* marker = '**text**'
- *end* marker = '**end**'
- *objective* = remove all text between last *start* marker and before the first *end* marker (actually replace all said text with a single space)

Input with all markers in **bold**:

> This **text** d #! more **text** jsdlj **end** and mo{re ;re **end** **text**.**text**

Input with the two markers of interest in **bold**:

> This text d #! more **text** jsdlj **end** and mo{re ;re end text.text

Desired result:

> This text d #! more text end and mo{re ;re end text.text

While we can use `sed` to remove the desired text (replace `<space>jsdlj<space>` with `<space>`), we have to deal with the fact that `sed` does greedy matching (fine for finding the 'last' *start* marker) but does not do non-greedy matching (needed to find the 'first' *end* marker). We can get around this limitation by switching out our *end* marker with a single-character replacement, simulate a non-greedy match, then switch back to the original *end* marker.

```
m1='text'               # start marker
m2='end'                # end marker

string="This text d #! more text jsdlj end and mo{re ;re end text.text"

sed -E "s/${m2}/@/g;s/(^.*${m1})[^@]*(@.*$)/\1 \2/;s/@/${m2}/g" <<< "${string}"
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable `E`xtended regex support (includes capture groups)
- `s/${m2}/@/g` - replace our end marker with the single character `@` (OP needs to determine what character cannot show up in expected input strings)
- `(^.*${m1})` - 1st capture group; greedy match from start of string up to last *start* marker before ...
- `[^@]*` - match everything that's not the `@` character
- `(@.*$)` - 2nd capture group; everything from `@` character until end of string
- `\1 \2` - replace entire string with 1st capture group + `<space>` + 2nd capture group
- `s/@/${m2}/g` - replace single character `@` with our *end* marker

This generates:

```
This text d #! more text end and mo{re ;re end text.text
```

Personally, I'd probably opt for a more straight forward parameter expansion approach (similiar to Jetchisel's answer) but that could be a bit problematic for inline `xargs` processing ... ???

---

**Original answer**

One `sed` idea using capture groups:

```
$ string="This text and more text jsdlj-end.text"
$ sed -En 's/(^.*text ).*(-end.*$)/\1\2/p' <<< "${string}"
This text and more text -end.text
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable `E`xtended regex support (and capture groups) and (`-n`) disable default printing of pattern space
- `(^.*text )` - first capture group = start of line up to last `text`
- `.*` - everything between the 2 capture groups
- `(-end.*$)` - second capture group = from `-end` to end of string
- `\1\2/p` - print the contents of the 2 capture groups.

Though this runs into issues if there are multiple `-end` strings on the 'end' of the string, eg:

```
$ string="This text and more text jsdlj-end -end.text"
$ sed -En 's/(^.*text ).*(-end.*$)/\1\2/p' <<< "${string}"
This text and more text -end.text
```

Whether this is correct or not depends on the desired output (and assuming this type of 'double' ending string is possible).

Comment: This also removes the text between the last occurance of the 1st capture group and the last occurance of the 2nd capure group. Needs to remove the text between the last occurance of the 1st capture group and the *first* occurance (afterwards) of the 2nd capure group. eg "text text text kJDSglkj-end 123-end 555-end end l;jds;gk " resuling with "text text text -end 123-end 555-end end l;jds;gk " Thanks for pointing this out - I've update the OP to clarify, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jkeys I've updated my answer with a new approach which (I think) addresses the latest updated question; keep in mind I'm only working with the provided input string ... not sure if/how this will work in your real world `xargs` requirement ....

Comment: thanks. I'll simulate it to check. Your breakdown is also very helpful in understanding it (for adaption, etc.)

Comment: ok, I missed that in the latest update; should be able to replace `\1<space>\2` with `\1\2`

Comment: just a fyi - the start maker already has a space in it 'text<space>', so its not replacing the text with a space, its just removing all text between the markers, keeping the makers intact. so it would be: sed -E "s/${m2}/@/g;s/(^.*${m1})[^@]*(@.*$)/\1\2/;s/@/${m2}/g" <<< "${string}" ?

Comment: correct; alternatively ... *When in doubt, try it out!*

Comment: This apperas to have worked. The results are removing the text between the 2 markers as follows - removes between the *last* start-maker and the *first* end-maker, leaving the markers there. eg "some text text text 9072kfgg end end end" with start="text " and end="end", results in "some text text text end end end".

Answer (score 3):

Using Bash's Regex match:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string='This text and more text jsdlj-end.text'
[[ $string =~ (.*text\ ).*(-end.*) ]] || :
printf %s\\n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Comment: This removes everything between the last start-maker and the last end-maker. Needs to remove everything between the last 'start-maker' and the first 'end-maker'. eg if the string was "text text text dsfkj end eho end hh" then the result needs to be "text text text end echo end hh". Instead the above results with "text text text end hh

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky using only a posix extended regex (ERE), but easy with a perl compatible regex (PCRE). Therefore, we switch from `sed` to `perl`:

To get the last `text` (that still has a `end` afterwards), put a `.*` in front. The closest `end` to that `text` can then be matched using a non-greedy `.*?`.

Here we also put `\b` around `text` and `end` to avoid matching parts of other words (for example, the word `send` should not be matched even though it contains `end` too).

```
perl -pe 's/(.*\btext\b).*?(\bend\b)/\1 \2/' <<< "$string"
```

Comment: I had issues using this as part of a find | xargs -0 ' command; command; command; ' _; script, with sed containing the ' quote.

Comment: For this expression the type of quotes does not matter. You can also use `sed -E "s/(.*text).*(-end)/\1\2/" <<< "$string"`, which can be embedded inside `'...'`. However, are you sure you want to run `sed` for each file individually. Depending on what you want to do, you could use `find ... -print0 | sed -z ...` which would be faster.

Comment: I'm using find to rename files (and do some other things, like loggin, etc) with xargs. I'm not sure how sed would work with running multiple commands

Comment: This one appears to also remove the text between the last occurance of the 'start-maker' and the last occurance of the 'end-marker'. I've updated the OP to clarify that it needs to remove the text between the last start-maker and the *first* occurance of the end-maker. Sorry for the confustion.

Comment: You mean you updated the question. OP is the author of the question (you). For the future: Please don't change your question in ways that invalidate existing answers (e.g. changing `-end` to `end`). I updated my answer.

Comment: sorry, my bad - you are right. I haven't been on here for several years so forgot consideration

Answer (score 2):

With [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
string="This text and more text jsdlj-end.text"
temp=${string%-*}
end=${string#"$temp"}
start=${temp% *}
echo "$start$end"
```

Comment: This one unforunately does not keep the start-maker (eg the space in $start) and it also removes the text between the last occurance of the start-maker and the last occurance of the end-maker. Needs to remove (only) the text beween the last occurance of the start-maker and the *first* occurance of the end-maker, leaving the makers intact. I've updated the OP to clarify.